# INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 50 threads ``for group Thread Group.enter code here                      
 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=50 ramp-

Comment: You will need to provide more context than this. As it is, it is not clear what you asking, what led to this apparent error message etc. Please look at [this]9https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to ask a question that will make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: While Performing Load Testing Is is Showing Thread will continue an error  and Randomly im getting errors for 50plus users in jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you show has nothing abnormal, it just tells you in which mode JMeter [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is working:

The possible choices are:

```
Continue - ignore the error and continue with the test
Start Next Thread Loop - ignore the error, start next loop and continue with the test
Stop Thread - current thread exits
Stop Test - the entire test is stopped at the end of any current samples.
Stop Test Now - the entire test is stopped abruptly. Any current samplers are interrupted if possible.
```

If you're randomly getting errors , cause can be very wide:

- an error in script where some correlation is missing
- the application not scaling and not able to handle the load

Have a look at server logs.